# Error while downloading images from a server

Tags: android, httpclient

I am getting this error from the logcat

> org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond.

What might be the reason?
My download code is as below.

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse)httpclient.execute(httpRequest);

HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
InputStream instream = bufHttpEntity.getContent();
bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(instream);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call following methods and pass in URL .

public Bitmap DownloadFromUrl(String imageURL) {  //this is the downloader method

```
        Bitmap bm=null;
            try {
                    URL url = new URL(imageURL); //you can write here any link



                   URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();


                  InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
                   BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);


                    ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
                   int current = 0;
                   while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                            baf.append((byte) current);
                   }

                  bm= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(baf.toByteArray(), 0, baf.toByteArray().length);


          } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d("ImageManager", "Error: " + e);
          }
            return bm;

    }
```

Comment: A couple of images downloaded and a couple of images missed. For missed images , i got this error : SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null

Answer (score 1):

`NoHttpResponseException` means one and only thing: the server closed connection without sending back an HTTP response message, most likely due to an abnormal condition encountered during processing of the request. In other words, this is most likely a server side bug.

Comment: I'd had you should catch that kind of exception and possibly IOExceptions too. For that kind of error have 3 choices, retry, cancel, ignore.